# Dynamic <div> height on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-apps-script

Hello Stack Overflow Community! I haven't really utilized this resource and basically learned how to work Google Apps Script from the ground up (with my very limited knowledge of scripting languages). I am having trouble with embedding jQuery into my Web App and I turn to the experts for help.

This is just a quick example I came up with to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. What I want is for the "container" div to have a dynamic height. That way, the whole screen is filled up, no matter what size it is (well, not a phone most likely). Here is the code:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('app').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

**stylesheet.html**

```
<style>

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: top;
}

#menu {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: top;
}

#container {
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

#footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

</style>
```

**javascript.html**

```
<script>

function adjust(){
  var maxH = $("#main").height();
  var afterHeight = maxH - ($("#header").height() - $("#menu").height() - $("#footer").height());
  $(".kamil_test").css({height:afterHeight});
}

$(document).ready(adjust);
$(window).resize(adjust);

</script>
```

**app.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js">
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>  

    <?!= include('stylesheet.html'); ?>
    <?!= include('javascript.html'); ?>

    <div id="main">
      <div id="header">
      </div>

      <div id="menu">
      </div>

      <div id="container">
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I think my post is too long, but I wanted to show what is going on from all four parts. Wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this and adapt it to what you are trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>CSS Layout - 100% height</title>
    <style type="text/css">


        html,body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
            background:gray;


        }



        div#container {
            position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
            margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
            width:750px;
            background:#f0f0f0;

            height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
            height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

            min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
        }

        div#header {
            padding:1em;
            background:#ddd url("../csslayout.gif") 98% 10px no-repeat;
            border-bottom:6px double gray;
        }
        div#header p {
            font-style:italic;
            font-size:1.1em;
            margin:0;
        }

        div#content {
            padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
        }
        div#content p {
            text-align:justify;
            padding:0 1em;
        }

        div#footer {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            bottom:0; /* stick to bottom */
            background:#ddd;
            border-top:6px double gray;
        }
        div#footer p {
            padding:1em;
            margin:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <h1>CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer</h1> 
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h2>Min-height</h2>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                This footer is absolutely positioned to bottom:0; of  #container. The padding-bottom of #content keeps me from overlapping it when the page is longer than the viewport.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>





</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one; it's fortunate that CSS has the ability to set a ceiling and a floor for the sizes of objects.

In your case, you want to set the floor (meaning the lowest possible value) of the height of your div to the height of the screen.

Answer:

```
min-height: 100%;
```

The div should already try to resize to allow it's contents to completely fit inside of it's volume. By adding this tag, the div will still resize OR if it's contents have a total height less than the height of the screen, the div will still remain the height of the screen.